# Error when deploying to modulus

Tags: node.js, meteor, modulus.io

I'm trying to deploy my first meteor app to modulus.io but I'm getting the following error in the log:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/mnt/data/cfs'
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:654:18)
at sync (/mnt/data/1/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:55:12)
at sync (/mnt/data/1/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:61:24)
at Function.sync (/mnt/data/1/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:61:24)
at new FS.Store.FileSystem (packages/cfs:filesystem/filesystem.server.js:37:1)
at app/leads.js:69:3
at app/leads.js:332:3
at /mnt/data/1/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
at Array.forEach (native)
at Function._.each._.forEach (/mnt/data/1/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
```

It's obviously something about permissions but don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to create a directory in `/mnt/data/cfs`, and you don't have permissions from the OS to do that. From quickly looking over the modulus.io documentation (http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1653448-file-storage), the platform allows you to write in exactly two directories: your local app directory, and `/mnt/data/tmp`. You are trying to write to a different directory. So that won't work.

Try using `/mnt/data/tmp/cfs` instead of `/mnt/data/cfs`.

It looks like you are using CollectionFS, and that package is using the directory in question. If that is the case, then you'll need to update the `path` option for that package:

```
var myStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("something", {
  path: "/mnt/data/tmp/cfs",
});
```

BTW, I had to infer a lot from your error (use of CFS, what directory you are trying to create). When asking questions, it is better 
to provide that sort of detail.

Comment: that made it, sorry for the lack of info when posting